# alg value for Ed25519?

Tags: jwt, jose, ed25519

The RFC7518 has a [list of algorithms values](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-3.1) used in JWT. However there is no value for `EdDSA`, such as `Ed25519`.  Also `Ed25519` is not accepted as a valid value when verifying in Jose. What is the correct alg value for `Ed25519`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ED25519 is an EdDSA ([Edwards-curve DSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA)) signature scheme. See also [RFC8037](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8037) and [RFC8032](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8032).

According to the [jose documentation](https://github.com/panva/jose#jose-support-matrix) `alg` needs to be set to `EdDSA`:

> JWS Algorithm: Edwards-curve DSA
> alg: EdDSA

`EdDSA`is also listed in the [section JSON Web Signature and Encryption Algorithms](https://www.iana.org/assignments/jose/jose.xhtml#web-signature-encryption-algorithms) of the IANA Registry (thanks @Florent Morselli for the hint)

---

Here I show an example how to generate an ed25519 keypair and a signed token using [Node.js Crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) and [jose](https://github.com/panva/jose), then verify the token with the public key in Python:

Generate key pair and token:

```js
const { SignJWT } = require('jose/jwt/sign')
const { generateKeyPairSync } = require('node:crypto')

const { publicKey, privateKey } = generateKeyPairSync('ed25519');
console.log(publicKey.export({format:'pem',type:'spki'}))
console.log(privateKey.export({format:'pem',type:'pkcs8'}))

const jwt = await new SignJWT({ 'id': 1 })
    .setProtectedHeader({ alg: 'EdDSA' })
    .setExpirationTime('2h')
    .sign(privateKey)

console.log(jwt)
```

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
> MCowBQYDK2VwAyEA7fySb/9h7hVH8j1paD5IoLfXj4prjfNLwOPUYKvsTOc=
> -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

> -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
> MC4CAQAwBQYDK2VwBCIEIIJtJBnTuKbIy5YjoNiH95ky3DcA3kRB0I2i7DkVM6Cf
> -----END PRIVATE KEY-----

> eyJhbGciOiJFZERTQSJ9.eyJpZCI6MX0.RAxBAQPFOxrCfgqb56eaAz9u2lByj-WEO-
> JWgJH3Cyx1o1Hwjn1pA2M4NgJeob9vb2Oaw4FOeYFr6_33XMTnAQ

The decoded token header:

```
{
  "alg": "EdDSA"
}
```

Verify the token in Python with [PyJWT](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/):

```py
import jwt

public_key = """-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MCowBQYDK2VwAyEA7fySb/9h7hVH8j1paD5IoLfXj4prjfNLwOPUYKvsTOc=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"""

token = 'eyJhbGciOiJFZERTQSJ9.eyJpZCI6MX0.RAxBAQPFOxrCfgqb56eaAz9u2lByj-WEO-JWgJH3Cyx1o1Hwjn1pA2M4NgJeob9vb2Oaw4FOeYFr6_33XMTnAQ'

decoded = jwt.decode(token, public_key, algorithms='EdDSA', verify=True)
print(decoded)
```

**Note:** [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) currently doesn't support the EdDSA/ED25519 algorithm, so you can't verify the token on that site. I also don't know about any other JWT website that can verify EdDSA signed tokens.