# Receiving "TypeError: sign() missing 1 required positional argument: 'algorithm'" with python PyJWT

Tags: python, digital-signature, dsa, pyjwt, eddsa

So I used the command:
`ssh-keygen -m PKCS8 -t dsa` to generate the following (example) key:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBSgIBADCCASsGByqGSM44BAEwggEeAoGBAIATtp/DhG2hDIT3DiMIctaxPn/s
FFxbXa4IIytk0b/PDBq9Kv/OeFv54h1L9iSLoNHrsx3dOR+6CyFyfnZT9s0yjpSe
uYiU6QVhX1sl24KzlpTXgu2vXlBx24vNq4adGmRROxtxjBaiAlN8va4oM0GT8hNG
sJ6uAWmFfYvqvnulAhUAtuiO7CyAzrkXcneK3qWYntor2w0CgYAYMEDqn+gjIfhx
IcZCA3eTUbuE4xAfzLwz0XSvUbaxYn9bJFmQ17F1vdnD1a4tEy7dyLj1EUNarNUF
P/T/BJdX7P4g+Fua96RuuvUkJ/gFshFBRWgyXyBsvydcZrbYhpSag8jwLo3QAuse
ulTIWyR8BRgYjmmCFIw0uNS86Kyu7wQWAhQtuXafDJ4JWDMpSPHxU+UwzbjfeA==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I am attempting to sign data with this key using the following snippet:

```py
import jwt

with open('./id_dsa', 'r') as file:
  key = file.read()
  print(key)
  token = jwt.encode({'some': 'data'}, key, algorithm='EdDSA')
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./client.py", line 23, in <module>
    token = jwt.encode({'username': args.username,'publicKey': args.pubKey}, key, algorithm='EdDSA')
  File "/home/walt/angi/auth/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 63, in encode
    return api_jws.encode(json_payload, key, algorithm, headers, json_encoder)
  File "/home/walt/angi/auth/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 114, in encode
    signature = alg_obj.sign(signing_input, key)
  File "/home/walt/angi/auth/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jwt/algorithms.py", line 578, in sign
    return key.sign(msg)
TypeError: sign() missing 1 required positional argument: 'algorithm'
```

I am not sure if the key I am generating is incorrect or what else I could be doing wrong.

Comment: Since that is three levels deep in the library you're using, also check the bug reports for that library and possibly file one yourself. Also relevant perhaps is the version. That said, it's enough to indent the `key = file.read()` line, because you don't need the file open after that.

Comment: *I am not sure if the key I am generating is incorrect* - it's indeed an incorrect key.  The error message of PyJWT is unfortunately quite misleading. The algorithm parameter `-t DSA` is wrong. The correct algorithm would be  `-t Ed25519`, but even then I haven't been able to get a key from ssh-keygen that works with PyJWT. In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66894047/7329832) I show how to create an Ed25519/EdDSA Key with Node.js, and that key worked fine with PyJWT.