# Signing a file using JWT with ed25519 encryption key

Tags: node.js, npm, jwt, ed25519, eddsa

I'm looking for a library that supports json object signing with jwt and ed25519 encryption key. I've looked around and couldn't find anything nodejs library that would support EdDSA type encryption.

The [jwt website](https://jwt.io/libraries) mentions [jose](https://github.com/panva/jose) as the only one that supports ed25519 encryption, but after going through the official documentation I was not able to confirm that it's the case...

In my understanding it should be as easy as

```
const signedJwt = jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, privateKey, { algorithm: 'EdDSA' });
```

I would appreciate any tips on how to achieve the goal whether it is library or a custom approach.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893790/alg-value-for-ed25519) help?

Comment: It does and the example works today. I swear I tried it yesterday and it was throwing me errors. Thank you for pointing me out there again.
Here is the link to my project in case someone else needs a template
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/governance-file-signing